# Is it good practice to consolidate small static tables in a database?

Tags: mysql, database, django

I am developing a database to store test data. Each piece of data has 11 tags of metadata. Currently I have a separate table for each of the metadata options. I have seen a few questions on here regarding best practices for numerous small tables, but I thought I'd pose the question for my own project because I didn't get a clear answer from the other questions asked.

Here is my table list, with the fields in each table:

```
Source Type - id, name, description
For Flight - id, name, description
Site - id, name, abrv, description
Stand - id, site (FK site table), name, abrv, descrition
Sensor Type - id, name, channels, descrition
Vehicle - id, name, abrv, descrition
Zone - id, vehicle (FK vehicle table), name, abrv, description
Event Type - id, name, description
Event - id, event type (FK to event type Table), name, descrition
Analysis - id, name, descrition
Bandwidth - id, name, descrition
```

You can see the fields are more or less the same in each of these tables. There are three tables that reference another table.

Would it be better to have just one large table called something like Meta with the following fields:

```
Meta: id, metavalue, name, abrv, FK, value, descrition
```

where metavalue = one of the above table names
and FK = a reference to another row in the Meta table in place of a foreign key?

I am new to databases and multiple tables seems most intuitive, but one table makes the programming easier.

So questions are:

1. Is it good practice to reduce the number of tables and put all static values in one table.
2. Is it bad to have a self referencing table.

FYI I am making this web database using django and mysql on a windows server with NTFS formatting.

Tips and best practices appreciate.

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Database Design - Multiple Lookup/Enum Tables or One Large Table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876008/database-design-multiple-lookup-enum-tables-or-one-large-table)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Would it be better to have just one large table" - emphatically and categorically, NO!

This anti-pattern is sometimes referred to as 'The one table to rule them all"!

[Ten Common Database Design Mistakes](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/ten-common-database-design-mistakes/): One table to hold all domain values.

> - Using the data in a query is much easier
> - Data can be validated using foreign key constraints very naturally,
>     something not feasible for the other
>     solution unless you implement ranges
>     of keys for every table – a terrible
>     mess to maintain.
> - If it turns out that you need to keep more information about a
>     ShipViaCarrier than just the code,
>     'UPS', and description, 'United Parcel
>     Service', then it is as simple as
>     adding a column or two. You could even
>     expand the table to be a full blown
>     representation of the businesses that
>     are carriers for the item.
> - All of the smaller domain tables will fit on a single page of disk.
>     This ensures a single read (and likely
>     a single page in cache). If the other
>     case, you might have your domain table
>     spread across many pages, unless you
>     cluster on the referring table name,
>     which then could cause it to be more
>     costly to use a non-clustered index if
>     you have many values.
> - You can still have one editor for all rows, as most domain tables will
>     likely have the same base
>     structure/usage. And while you would
>     lose the ability to query all domain
>     values in one query easily, why would
>     you want to? (A union query could
>     easily be created of the tables easily
>     if needed, but this would seem an
>     unlikely need.)

Comment: Adamant answer noted. Can you explain a bit why it is not a good idea to cluster a bunch of small tables together? Is it because in the future i may want to expand and this is the most versatile solution?

Comment: Plesae see the linked article, Louis Davidson explains better than I could.

Comment: Thanks that was an informative and extensive article. I will try to incorporate 'surrogate keys' into my tables to make sure there is an element intelligible to the human eye as well as maintain the normalized meta tables I initially conceived.

Comment: it seemed more people had comments to make and I didn't want to close out the discussion. Not sure if accepting an answer does in fact do that but I thought I'd err on the safe side.

Comment: @sequoia : OK. Thanks, I was just curious.

Answer (score 1):

Most of these look like they won't do anything but expand codes into descriptions.  Do you even need the tables?  Just define a bunch of constants, or codes, and then have a dictionary of long descriptions for the codes.

The field in the referring table just stores the code. eg: "SRC_FOO", "EVT_BANG" etc.

Comment: Well i chose tables because not all  of the meta values have been defined. In future testing we may use new values and i thought it would be easiest to just add a new value to a table. We will have new analysis techniques, new choices of bandwidth, new zones, etc. So when future data is entered new values will just get added to the appropriate table the value doesn't currently exist. -- but essentially you are right, the tables store, short static values, such as source_foo or event_bang. where would I define the dictionaries? and are they a good idea if the lists could grow?

Comment: putting them in constants means the code needs to be recompileed for small changes. I'd steer away from that as a solution.

Comment: Putting them in the database means you need to make more database calls or implement a caching strategy. It is also a bit more difficult to localize the descriptions to different languages if required.  There are pros and cons for either method, but ultimately they are both workable solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This is also often known as the One True Lookup Table (OTLT) - see my old blog entry [OTLT and EAV: the two big design mistakes all beginners make](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.com/2004/10/otlt-and-eav-two-big-design-mistakes.html).